# A short cut to a Classic problem of 3 linear equations with 3 unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$a^3x+a^2y+az-1=0$$
$$b^3x+b^2y+bz-1=0$$
$$c^3x+c^2y+cz-1=0$$
This seems a classic equation that we can solve it  by eliminating one unknown and reduce the system to  two equations with two variables . My question is Is there a short cut that I can not get lost  by $a^3, b^2$......and so on.Thanks

Comment: Just rename, say $\alpha_3=a^3$, $\alpha_2=a^2$ and so on.

Comment: Probably related to the [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).

Comment: I think you should look at [Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Explicit_formulas_for_small_systems). Also, the tip on Vandermonde matrix is good in order to calculate determinants appearing.

Answer (score 1):

This system is equivalent to the following one:
$$
abcx-1=0,\; abcy + a + b + c=0,\; - abcz + ab + ac + bc =0.
$$

Comment: I agree, but how is OP supposed to see that?

Comment: $Ax=(1,1,1)^T$ with Vandermonde matrix $A$. Or by using a CAS. It is helpful to get used to a CAS "early".

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Would you please explain your solution for someone with high school knowledge of math.

Comment: @max: on high school level your proposed solution above is perfect. I did just as you said. If you want to learn something above high school level, then read the Vandermonde article and linear algebra.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde Thanks for your hint I found an article SOLUTION OF VANDERMONDE SYSTEMS OF EQUATIONS By Ake Björck* and Victor Pereyra. Of course Only God knows how much of it I will understand.